How to perform AzureRM update for release tasks
We started receiving warnings regarding the AzureRM for updates since it is retiring soon:

2024-09-27T01:14:07.8264879Z ##[warning]You're using AzureRM which will be retired soon, please schedule an update.

After conducting an investigation, we identified that while we are not using scripts that directly call the AzureRM commands, the task defined in our release pipeline is utilizing Azure Resource Manager.
Issue:
We did not find any documentation mentioning the retirement of this specific task definition. This raises the following questions:

Are we supposed to update this task to use the Az PowerShell task?

How long will this task be supported


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm-retirement-overview?view=azps-12.3.0

AzureRM PowerShell module has been  deprecated for a while. Please note that the module and the pipeline task are 2 different things.

Hi @Arif, Have you got a chance to check the answer below by RUI? The AzurePowerShell@ task running on Microsoft-hosted agents already uses the latest Az modules and has no plan for retirement. Hope your query in this post can be resolved. Thx for the sharing.

Hi @Arif, Good day. If the answer by RUI can resolve your query in this post, you may consider this, which may help others with similar concerns. Thanks and have a nice weekend.

Were you able to find a replacement for the AzureRmWebAppDeployment Pipelines task?

I think you might be confusing the module (AzureRM) with the pipeline task (AzurePowerShell).

##[warning]You're using AzureRM which will be retired soon, please schedule an update.

The above warning is related to the AzureRM PowerShell module, which has been officially deprecated as of February 29, 2024. Users are advised to migrate from AzureRM to the Az PowerShell module to ensure continued support and updates.

We did not find any documentation mentioning the retirement of this specific task definition

AFAIK there is no plan to deprecate/retire the pipeline task. Also, there's no such thing as an "Az PowerShell task" (i.e. task that uses exclusively the Az module). You can continue using the AzurePowerShell@x tasks to run any PowerShell scripts within an Azure environment.
EDIT
As per Azure Pipelines Tasks - issue #19843, using Powershell core might prevent the warning from being displayed:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    # ...
    #pwsh: true # Use PowerShell Core

Adding environment variable RETIRE_AZURERM_POWERSHELL_MODULE and setting it to true will also dismiss the warning. However, Uninstall-AzureRM is called on every execution:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    # ...
  env:
    RETIRE_AZURERM_POWERSHELL_MODULE: true

Please refer to the link above for more details.

We are using the -AzureRmWebAppDeployment@x to task to deploy code to web app, when I disable those task , I don't see those warnings , since we are not importing AzureRMModule explicitly if the pipeline task are not retiring , not sure where is this warnings coming from

@Arif are you using self-hosted agents? Is the AzureRM module installed? What happens if you uninstall it? Double-check your scripts. Also, could you please edit your question and paste the code of the task/script that generates the warning(s)?

@Arif try adding the RETIRE_AZURERM_POWERSHELL_MODULE and set it to true in your AzureRmWebAppDeployment task, as mentioned in my edit. Yes it's a different task but it might work.

Hi @Arif, As Rui suggested, can you share more details about your agent and let us know the update from your side? Thx.
